# form validation for a changing form name

Tags: javascript

I have a arrary of forms that is created dynamically using php.

The form name is created using a php $formcount variable and incremented using a while loop. So for multiple forms created, the form name will be: 
update1
update2
update3 and so on.

I have a dropdown menu in each form which needs to be validated. I am not able to use JavaScript successfully to validate each form seperately as the name of the form keeps changing everytime.

```
$formcount=0;
while($info=mysql_fetch_array($agent_q))
{
......
echo('
<form name="update'.$formcount.'" method="post" onsubmit="return CheckUpdate(this);">
<select name="login_time" id="login_time">
<option value="none">Select Login</option>
<option value="00:30">00:30</option>
<option value="02:30">02:30</option>
<option value="03:30">03:30</option>
<option value="04:30">04:30</option>
<option value="06:30">06:30</option>
<option value="09:30">09:30</option>
<option value="12:30">12:30</option>
<option value="13:30">13:30</option>
<option value="16:30">16:30</option>
<option value="17:30">17:30</option>
<option value="18:30">18:30</option>
<option value="19:30">19:30</option>
<option value="20:30">20:30</option>
<option value="21:30">21:30</option>
<option value="22:30">22:30</option>
</select></form>');
.....
}
```

my JS is

```
function CheckUpdate(){
    if(document.????==0){
    alert("Select Login Time!\r\n");
    return false;
    }
    else
    return true;
}
```

not sure what to put in place of ???. I am sure this is something rather easy.. any help is highly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to approach it.  Probably the most straightforward (without having to modify your existing PHP) would be to use the [`form.elements`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/form.elements) collection. In your case, the `<select>` would be `elements[0]`

```
// The form node is passed in the function call as (this)
function CheckUpdate(node){
    // The first form element in the form node passed to the function is the <select>
    // Test that a value other than the default is selected...
    if (node.elements[0].value == 'none'){
      alert("Select Login Time!\r\n");
      return false;
    }
    else return true;
}
```

There are other ways to manage this as well. For example, if there is always only one `<select>` inside the `<form>`, but it isn't necessarily in the first position `[0]`, you could use `getElementsByTagName()` to retrieve it as a child of the current `<form>`

```
function CheckUpdate(node){
    var selNodes = node.getElementsByTagName('select');
    // Check the value of the first <select> child of the <form> (which was passed as node)
    if (selNodes[0].value == 'none'){
      alert("Select Login Time!\r\n");
      return false;
    }
    else return true;
}
```

Note: In your PHP loop, you are *duplicating* the `<select>` id attribute. This is not allowed - id attributes are supposed to be unique. You may append your `$formcount`.

```
echo '
<form name="update'.$formcount.'" method="post" onsubmit="return CheckUpdate(this);">
<select name="login_time" id="login_time' . $formcount . '">
...;
```

Comment: There were more then one input field in the form, select was in the fourth place... so I tried node.elements[3].value == 'none' , worked perfectly fine :). I did not need the select id attribute as it was not serving any purpose so I removed it.

Is there an option to get all dump of all that is sent in the form function? I know there is one in php : var_dump($_POST)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<form name="update'.$formcount.'" id="update'.$formcount.'" method="post" onsubmit="return CheckUpdate(this);">

function CheckUpdate(form){
    if(document.form.login_time.value == 0){
    alert("Select Login Time!\r\n");
    return false;
    }
    else
    return true;
}
```